# Программа для отправки смс-сообщений на java

Tags: java

Нужно написать программу для отправки смс-сообщений с ПК на мобильный телефон. 
Язык программирования : Java.
Какие библиотки нужно для этого использовать?
И вообще какой принцип работы такого рода программ?

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас к ПК не подключено специальных устройств с СИМ-картой, то сами вы никак не отправите, но... вы всегда можете приобрести подобную услугу у некоторых провайдеров.

Они как правило предоставляют web api: посылаете из программы запрос к специальному сайту, а сервер, обрабатывающий запрос имеет подключенную железку, которая умеет обрабатывать СМСки.

Вид API может отличаться и описан в документации провайдера услуги.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предположить, что тебе нужно отправлять запросы на сайт, который предоставляет возможность отправки смс. Тоесть программа обрабатывает запрос и переадресует его на подобный сайт, который уже отправляет само смс.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow на русском! Пожалуйста, пишите более подробные ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки SMS используются специальные сервисы по типу:

- [smsc.ru](https://smsc.ru)
- [mainsms.ru/](https://mainsms.ru/)

На сайтах подробно описана схема интеграции. Обычно это сводится к вызову API методов через HTTP (REST). Или же, если у сервиса имеется специальное Java API, то достаточно добавить предоставляемую сервисом библиотеку к проекту и дергать нужные методы.

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент занят такое же проблемой, если есть  GSM модем и работать будет на Линуксе есть Sms Server tools 3,  очень хорошая программа, отправляет и принимает Sms,   на окна тоже можно, а если только на Java есть библиотека для работы с com портом Jssc.